# How does the javascript behind Google Images work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Recently, Google Images [redesigned](https://plus.google.com/+google/posts/eQHPcukkr8S) their site so a large lightbox opens up when you click an image. You can press arrow keys to advance the photo. Does anyone know how it works?

I assume they have divs between the rows, but how do they determine where a row ends or where the next div to expand is? Do they recalculate everything using an onResize event?

I'm pretty new to jQuery so this might be obvious.

EDIT: I should note that for my project all the images are the same size, so I don't need a dynamic layout plugin.

Answer (score 4):

Google appear to use their own code but you should be able to achieve similar based on the following client-side software :

- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)
- A "dynamic tiling" process, eg. the jQuery plugin [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)
- An "infinite-scroll" effect eg. the jQuery plugin [infinitescroll](https://github.com/diy/jquery-infinitescroll)

Please note, I said "based on". You still need to provide :

- server-side code to serve data/HTML,
- some way to /compose/insert/hide the "lightbox" (partly handled by Masonry),
- some way to give the required arrow-key functionality

Comment: Thanks! I should have mentioned all my images are the same size, so I don't need a Masonry-type plugin.

Comment: @BenGartner well, that makes things a little bit easier :-)